# How can i add label tag in ActiveAdmin view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have rendered selects. But i can't add "for" attribute for my label tag.
How it's make right?
Thanks.

```
i = 1
counties.each do |county|
 li class: "city" do
   span id: "check_#{i}" do
     check_box_tag county.name, county.id
   end
   label for: "check_#{i}", class: "city-name-main" do
     county.name
   end
   i += 1
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

f.input :countries, as: :check_boxes, :multiple => true, member_label: :name

member_label set label to checkboxes. contries is the namr of nested model. When you want set a collectionn do this

f.input :countrie, as: :check_boxes, :multiple => true, member_label: :name,collection: Countries.all.map{|t| [t.country_name, t.id]}

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the `:for` attribute has [special meaning](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre/blob/fe4738844d7d4b9db0b1b46af889310854cd316e/lib/arbre/html/tag.rb#L19) in the [Arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre) library and is used to identify the ActiveModel associated with the tag. So, `for` is one of the few HTML attributes that cannot be set with the Arbre DSL.

Depending on your use case you could instead render a partial with ERB (or another template library). Or assuming you're adding check boxes to an ActiveAdmin form, it could be accomplished via formtastic within the ActiveAdmin form block:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :country, as: :check_boxes, collection: counties
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe a ticket should be created for this?

Comment: Yeah, I'd think so. It would require some changes in both Arbre and ActiveAdmin.

Comment: I added an issue to the Arbre project identifying this problem: [Arbre #18](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre/issues/18)